# Charts не отображают ограничители в соответственном виде

Tags: javascript, диаграммы, highcharts

Есть 6 графиков , 2 графика я привязал и они работают циклично пока что,но линии(пределы) сдвинулись в бок все ,а должно быть как на изображении графики ЧАО 2.3   ЧАО 2.4 ,там отображается как нужно .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**скрипт первого графика**

```
   <!-- скрипт для прорисовки необходимой гистограммы 1 -->
<script>


var chart21 = new Highcharts.chart('gistorgam1', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'ЧАО-2.1'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    exporting: {
                enabled: false,
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        menuItems: ['downloadCSV', 'downloadXLS']
                    }
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        },
        scatter:{
            marker:{
                symbol:'square',
                lineWidth:50,
                Height:2,
                radius:1,
                lineColor:'#333'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> за последнее время<br/>'
    },

    series: [
        {   
            dataLabels: { enabled: true },

            name: "Окатыши",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [

                {
                    "color": 'rgba(172,199,255,255)',
                    "name": "-10",
                    "y": 2,
                },
                {
                     "color": 'rgba(188,255,218,255)',
                    "name": "10-12,5",
                    "y": 20,
                },
                {
                     "color": 'rgba(200,240,255,255)',
                    "name": "12,5-14",
                    "y": 55,
                },
                {
                     "color": 'rgba(255,191,191,255)',
                    "name": "14-18",
                    "y": 60,
                },
                {
                     "color": 'rgba(227,208,241,255)',
                    "name": "18+",
                    "y": 32,
                },
            ]
        },{ states: { hover: { enabled: false } },
            marker: { symbol: 'url(images/avgicon.jpg)' },
            type:'scatter',
            data: [10, 20.5, 30.4, 40.2, 14.0],
            enableMouseTracking: false // УБРАТЬ ПОДСКАЗКИ}
          }
   ]
});





</script>
```

**Мне кажется что я здесь что-то не правильно сделал**

```
  <script>

var_1=1;
var_2=1;
var_3=1;

function get_inform() {

    var_1 = var_1+1
    var_2 = var_2+3
    var_3 = var_3+5

    if(var_1>20){
        var_1=1;
        var_2=1;
        var_3=1;
    }

 series = chart21.series[0];    
 series.data[0].update({ y: var_1 }, true); 
 series.data[1].update({ y: var_2 }, true); 
 series.data[2].update({ y: var_3 }, true); 





    chart.redraw();  


    setTimeout(get_inform, 500);    
}

get_inform();   // запрос информации с сервера    

</script>
```

Comment: зачем вы срабатывание по таймеру делаете с помощью таймаута? приведите нормальный код сниппет, чтобы было с чем работать. Попробуйте просто `update(var_1)` без объекта, просто значение. и зачем тут `chart.redraw()` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/point-update-column/ здесь ведь все работает вроде, аналогичное.

Comment: Дело в другом . Поверх каждого столбца есть оранжевый ограничитель ,так вот как только я обрабатываю series.data[0].update({ y: var_1 }, ограничители сьезжают сразу на 6 столбец как видно на изображении

Comment: с x-координатой там проблема какая то, а не "съезжает". добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример здесь или на jsfiddle, иначе гадание на кофейной гуще тут.

Comment: Оно и здесь  не будет нормально отображаться . Если можете ,зайдите пожалуйста через тимвьюер ID-1 360 485 876     LOG- 3zg45h   буквально на 2 минутки